# jQuery off() not removing click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  EnableModal();
});

function EnableModal() {
  if (isModalEnabled) { return; }

  // Initialize modal dialog
  // attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
  // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
  $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
  });

}

function DisableModal() {
  $('body').off('click', '.modal-link');
}
```

I am attempting to turn this off under certain circumstances, so I am calling:

```
$('body').off('click', '.modal-link');
```

However, the button with the `modal-link` class is still allowing click events through.  I see no errors in the developers console.

I have verified it is calling these correctly and that each is only being called once in my test case.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the "certain circumstances?"

Comment: If a user modifies text in a textbox, I call a function that calls the 'off' section.  That is all working as expected.

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: I guess provided code works in normal circumstances..You need to provide those *certain circumstances* to give better view! When will `DisableModal()` get called ?

Comment: It does not work in any circumstances.  What I was saying is I am only trying to call the off() method in certain circumstances.  It currently attempts to turn it off, it just doesn't remove it.  I have verified this via the usual routes, including putting simple alerts() into the two functions.

Comment: @Patrick, Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tmguumy1/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this issue before. I wasn't sure what happened at the very beginning and wonder if it was because the selectors weren't actually the same. I checked them and found out they were the same but still couldn't remove the event handler.

I finally fixed this by giving a dummy function as event handler after I removed the original one.

```
function DisableModal() {
$('body').off('click', '.modal-link');
$('body').on('click', '.modal-link', () => {});
}
```

Feel free to use ES5 version if you don't like the lambda expression. as

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:

```js
var isModalEnabled;

$(document).ready(function () {
  EnableModal();
  $(".disableModal").click(DisableModal);
});

function EnableModal() {
  if (isModalEnabled) { return; }

  // Initialize modal dialog
  // attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
  // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
  $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
  });

}

function DisableModal() {
  $('body').off('click', '.modal-link');
}
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
[data-target='#modal-container'] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click a few "Modal Link" buttons, and watch the button text turn bold.  Then click the "Disable Modal" button, and click the remaining "Modal Link" buttons.  The button text does <em>not</em> turn bold.</p>
<button class="modal-link">Modal Link</button>
<button class="modal-link">Modal Link</button>
<button class="modal-link">Modal Link</button>
<p><button class="disableModal">Disable Modal</button></p>
<button class="modal-link">Modal Link</button>
<button class="modal-link">Modal Link</button>
<button class="modal-link">Modal Link</button>
<p>To reset, click the "Run code snippet" button above.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the real cause of this, maybe the solution is to use namespaced events.

```
$('body').on('click.modal', '.modal-link', function (e) { });
```

and to remove it

```
$('body').off('.modal');
```

But I have a feeling it has nothing to do with this, but with the real issue is with the bootstrap modal. Maybe you need to clean up those attributes.

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').removeAttr("data-target data-toggle");
```